# finding the first value that is out of a range that is defined by other columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': list('abcdefghi'),
        'open': [6, 8, 12, 5, 6, 22, 19, 1, 3],
        'high': [10, 12, 20, 5, 2, 44, 11, 12, 5],
        'low': [5, 7, 3, 1, 3, 18, 12, 1, 7],
    }
)
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
  date  open  high  low     x
0    a     6    10    5     c
1    b     8    12    7     NaN
2    c    12    20    3     f
3    d     5     5    1     NaN
4    e     6     2    3     NaN
5    f    22    44   18     h 
6    g    19    11   12     NaN
7    h     1    12    1     NaN
8    i     3     5    7     NaN
```

I want to add column `x`. We start from first row. A range is defined by using columns `high` and `low`. Since we have started from first row the range is [5, 10]. Now I have to find the first open that is out of this range. There is 12 in third row. So in column `x` we put the `date` that the first out-of-range open occurred which is `c`.

Now our new range is defined in the row that has the date of `c`. So the new range is [3, 20]. We have to find the first open that is out of this range now. It occurs at the row that its `date` is `f`.

Now like the above process our range is defined by the row that its `date` is `f`. So our new range is [18, 44]. The first open that is out of this range occurs at the row that its `date` is `h`. So we put `h` in column `x`.

I have tried to use two masks to find the first out-of-range `open` but it didn't work. This is my try:

```
mask1 = (df.open > df.high)
mask2 = (df.open < df.low)
df.loc[mask1.cumsum().eq(1) | mask2.cumsum().eq(1), 'x'] = df.date
```

Comment: The search for first out of the range open value starts from the 1st row or next row of a particular range?

Comment: @HimanshuPanwar The `open` value is always in between `high` and `low` (based on what "open", "high", and "low" mean in this context), so you might as well start with the next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {}
curr_ind = df.index[0]

while True:
    low, high = df.low[curr_ind], df.high[curr_ind]
    open_ = df.open.loc[curr_ind:]
    if open_.gt(high).any() or open_.lt(low).any():
        next_ind = (open_.gt(high) | open_.lt(low)).idxmax()
        d[curr_ind] = df.date[next_ind]
        curr_ind = next_ind
    else:
        break

pd.concat([df, pd.Series(d, name="x")], axis=1)
#   date  open  high  low    x
# 0    a     6    10    5    c
# 1    b     8    12    7  NaN
# 2    c    12    20    3    f
# 3    d     5     5    1  NaN
# 4    e     6     2    3  NaN
# 5    f    22    44   18    h
# 6    g    19    11   12  NaN
# 7    h     1    12    1  NaN
# 8    i     3     5    7  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Since every value depends on previous values in different ways, it is not as easy as some masking and filtering. You need to apply some logic.

Probably not the most beautiful way, but this works:

```py
x = []
for i1, data1 in df.iterrows():
    if (isinstance(x1, str)) and (data1['date'] < x1):
        x.append(np.nan)

    else:
        x1 = np.nan
        df2 = df[df.index>i1]
        for i2, data2 in df2.iterrows():
            if (data2['open'] > data1['high']) or (data2['open'] < data1['low']):
                x1 = data2['date']
                break
            else:
                pass
            if isinstance(x1, str):
                break
        x.append(x1)

        
df['x'] = x
```

Result:

```py
df.x.tolist()
# Output: ['c', nan, 'f', nan, nan, 'h', nan, nan, nan]
```